# Find if the drupal node is published or not published in node_save()

Tags: 6, nodes

I am trying to find if the user has set the node to be published when creating a node. Upon hitting save, the call to `node_save()` is done; I tried to call `print_r($node)`, but nothing seems to show up in the data which relates to the publishing status of the node.

How would I find out if the node is set to be published? Is there a way I can find out if an alias is set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `$node->status`. The Node module defines two constants which you can use instead of 0/1 to make your code more readable:

```
/**
 * Node is not published.
 */
define('NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED', 0);

/**
 * Node is published.
 */
define('NODE_PUBLISHED', 1);
```

Example:

```
if ($node->status == NODE_PUBLISHED) {
  // Node is published.
}
```

Note that you should *not* alter `node_save()`. Instead, implement [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) to do something either before (`$op` is "presave") or after (`$op` is "insert"/"update") the node is saved.

Comment: Question is tagged for Drupal 6.

Comment: Ah, overlooked that. Updated accordingly.